# How to print second largest number in an array using C?

Tags: c

I am new in C and i have been struggling to find the second largest index value.
the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i,max=0,smax=0;
    int A[] = {2,44,6,8,9,10,47};
    int n=7;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(A[max]<A[i]){
            smax=max;
            max=i;
        }
        else if(A[max]>A[i]){
            smax=i;
        }
    }
    printf("First value: %d\n",A[max]);
    printf("Second value: %d",A[smax]);
    return 0;
}
```

Now when i run the program,it is showing me this:

```
First value: 44
Second value: 9
```

What should i do to fix this?

Comment: Explain the purpose of `else if(A[max]>A[i])`. Logically, that part of the program would be handling "the number was not larger than the maximum, so now test the secondary maximum". Is that what this code _actually_ does? Rhetorical question.

Comment: @paddy the purpose of the else if is that if the second index is less than the first then the index i will be transferred to smax

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica They iterate from second element because first is assumed as largest. It's all ok with `i=1` in the loop.

Comment: @Suborno Okay so now read that actual code and convince me it does what you say it does. I'll bet you can't (convince me, that is). It's actually baffling that there are now two answers, none of which seem to understand the fundamentally-flawed logic. So I guess you shouldn't feel bad that you're struggling with this simple program.

Comment: Yes i cant because i am still new to this and i cant even figure out what should i pass in else if. i was actually looking forward for a little help(cause i did most of it) and here i am being roasted with your ego. thanks for the tip i will try to do this myself.

Answer (score 1):

In my solution, I first initialize `max` and `smax` by looking only at the first two elements of the array. Afterwards, I check all remaining array elements to determine whether any of them is larger than `smax`. If I find one that is larger than `smax`, I check whether it is also larger than `max`, and act accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int max, smax;

    int A[] = { 2, 44, 6, 8, 9, 10, 47 };

    //set n to length of array
    const int n = sizeof A / sizeof *A;

    //make sure that the array has at least two values
    if ( n < 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Array must contain at least two values!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //initialize max and smax by processing the first two
    //elements of the array
    if ( A[0] > A[1] )
    {
        max  = 0;
        smax = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        max  = 1;
        smax = 0;
    }

    //process the remaining elements of the array
    for( int i = 2; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( A[i] > A[smax] )
        {
            if ( A[i] > A[max] )
            {
                smax = max;
                max = i;
            }
            else
            {
                smax = i;
            }
        }
    }

    //print the results
    printf( "Highest value: %d\n", A[max] );
    printf( "Second-highest value: %d", A[smax] );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Highest value: 47
Second-highest value: 44
```

Comment: Just tried your code with the array `{ 50, 50, 49 }`. It becomes a philosophical question as to whether the "second highest" means _less-than-or-equal_ or simply _less-than_...

Answer (score 1):

Given the presence of other answers, it may seem glib, but you could simply sort your array in descending order and then pick the second element.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int int_cmp_desc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int x = *(int *)a;
    int y = *(int *)b;

    return x == y ? 0 :
           x <  y ? 1 : -1;
}

int main(void) {
    int A[] = {2,44,6,8,9,10,47};
    size_t sz = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
    int B[sz];

    memcpy(B, A, sizeof(A));
    qsort(B, sz, sizeof(*B), int_cmp_desc);
    printf("%d\n", B[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if you need the second largest *unique* number, this will make that easier too.

```c
int main(void) {
    int A[] = {2,44,6,8,9,10,47,47};
    size_t sz = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
    int B[sz];

    memcpy(B, A, sizeof(A));
    qsort(B, sz, sizeof(*B), int_cmp_desc);
    printf("%d\n", B[1]);

    int first_number = B[0];
    size_t i = 1;

    // Advance index until it's at the next-to-last position.
    // If it's there and we still haven't found a unique element, 
    // index will advance to the last element of the array, which
    // we can then print.
    while (i < sz - 1 && B[i] == first_number) i++;

    printf("%d\n", B[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
47
44
```

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]:- I have finally ade this program not while ago and this works perfectly:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int arr[] = {2,4,6,28,19,12,11};
    int n=7,max=0,smax=0,i;
    for( i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(arr[max]<arr[i]){
            smax=max;
            max=i;
        }
        else if(arr[smax]<arr[i] && arr[max]!=arr[i]){
            smax=i;
        }
        else if(n==0){
             printf("The array is empty");
             return 0;
        }
        else if(n>=1){
             printf("The array has only one element");
             return 0;
        }
    printf("%d\n",arr[max]);
    printf("%d\n",arr[smax]);
}
```

Before that, I misunderstood the concept of else if but now its works.

Comment: it does not work for: 1. empty array 2. array with single element 3. array where all elements are the same

Comment: I modified the code that goes well when the array has more than one similar elements. And as for the single or Null elements that should be depend upon the user

Comment: it still does not work for all mentioned cases, what prevents you from quickly trying?

Comment: I have modified this code and now i guess it will work for all the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

finding largest and second largest problem is quite standard interview question with very simple description, but not so obvious solution, it is intended to check how you handle edge cases:

1. empty input array - in this case there is no any largest at all, so you have to think how you represent it
2. single element array - in this case there is no second largest, again you need to think how you represent it
3. array where all elements are the same - you need to clarify what the second largest actually means, can it be the same as largest one or it should be different, then again - you don't have second largest

here is variant which finds largest and second different largest:

```
void printMaxAnd2ndMax(int* a, int n) {
    int max = -1;
    int smax = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (max == -1 || a[i] > a[max]) {
            smax = max;
            max = i;
        }
        else if ((smax == -1 || a[i] > a[smax]) && (a[i] != a[max])) {
            smax = i;
        }
    }

    if (max >= 0)
        printf("Largest value: %d\n", a[max]);
    else
        printf("No largest value\n");
    if (smax >= 0)
        printf("Second value: %d", a[smax]);
    else
        printf("No second largest value\n");
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 2,44,6,8,9,10,47 };
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    printMaxAnd2ndMax(a, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your value of n is wrong; it should be 7, not 5. This is why your "biggest" value is found to be 44, because 47 is not even checked by the loop.

The most straightforward way I could think of is to sort the array. If you use the default setting, then the second last element would be the second largest. If you use a custom sort for descending order, then access the second element (i.e., element "1").

If you want to do it without sort, then theoretically you would have to loop through the array twice: once to find the maximum and the second time (excluding the maximum) to find the second maximum. However, this does present some problems, for example when the maximum element occurs more than once. (I'm assuming you would say that 3 is the second biggest element in the set {1, 2, 3, 3})
Hence, without using sorting, you would have to loop through the array twice. The first time, to find the maximum value and store the index of that value. The second time, finding the "maximum" excluding the stored value.

Here is my implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int array[] = {2,44,6,8,9,10,47};
  int i = 0, max_v = array[0], max_i = 0, smax = array[0];
  int n = 7;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (array[i] > max_v) {
      max_v = array[i];
      max_i = i;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == max_i) {
      i = max_i;
    } else {
      if (array[i] > smax) {
        smax = array[i];
      }
    }
  }

  printf("First value: %d\nSecond value: %d\n", max_v, smax);

  return 0;

}
```